# ngIf statement is executed multiple times in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 and I have a problem using `ngIf` directive. The problem is that the ngIf directive statement is executed multiple times. Pay attention to `*ngIf="isLoggedIn()"`.

I have this in `tab3.page.html`

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab Three
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
      <div class="ion-padding">
        <ion-button expand="block" type="submit" class="ion-no-margin" routerLink="/tabs/tab3/register">Sign up</ion-button>
        <br>
        <ion-button expand="block" type="submit" class="ion-no-margin" routerLink="/tabs/tab3/login">Log in</ion-button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
      You are logged in
    </div> -->
    <p *ngIf="isTrue()">
      Paragraph. True.
    </p>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

and I have this in `tab3.page.ts`

```js
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    console.log('isLoggedIn called');
    let logged: boolean = false;
    return logged;
    // this.authService.loggedIn()
    // .then( val => {
    //   logged = val;
    // });
    // return logged;
  }

  isTrue() {
    console.log('isTrue() called');
    return true;
  }
```

In the browser console, this is the output

[image]

could anyone explain this behavior of calling `isLoggedIn()` and `isTrue()` multiple times by ngIf directive?

Comment: please google or check attached link: [change detection cycle](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-change-detection-in-angular).

Comment: Functions called from template will be called on each change detection cycle. You should almost never call functions from templates. Call it once on `ngOnInit` and save it to a property of your component.

Comment: @ritaj makes sense. this seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

> Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements.

[Structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directives)

`*ngIf` is checking every time if the data you passed in it is true or false. So in your case it's calling `isLoggedIn()` or `isTrue()` several times to check is the result has changed.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Alexis' answer, the function is evaluated regularly (I call this "polling") to check if status has changed.

If you think this has a performance hit, you could use a property instead, and update it accordingly when it's needed. 
This lead to potentially much more code all around your component where the value needs to be updated, though.