# Call a finction and get return value directly in html better or set return value in a variable and use this variable in html better?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question about Call a finction and get return value directly in html better or set return value in a variable and use this variable in html better?

in the html

```
<div ngIf=isValid()>

</div>
```

in ts file:

```
public isValid(): boolean {


}
```

is this way better or

```
<div ngIf=isValid>

</div>
```

in ts file:

```
public isValid = false;
public isValidValue(): void {

if(){
 isValid = true;
}

}
```

which way ist better?

Comment: even im curious better to ask this question in the angular official github, instead of here, there is nothing about this in the documentation!

Comment: You should avoid function in template, because template will call it without condition, so depending on the function's complexity, you could have lack of performance. So you must use variable, or pipe.

Comment: @Alexis Could you give a source from official documentation, code in HTML is not testable, nor is there any proof that executing a function instead of a variable can crash your application, when performing simple actions inside the function, not complex actions\

Comment: Of course, if the function is just a setter or getter it will not have serious effect to performance. I already answered this kind of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629380/ngif-statement-is-executed-multiple-times-in-ionic-4/59629650#59629650). The template will check the value of what you pass on the template every time to check if it changed. So with a variable it just checks the value, with a function it executes the function to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article on this. Though it is not official this guys points are legit.

https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Main point to be taken from this article are

- Function calls are called multiple times on angular change detection cycles(this can be many times).
- In some case your simple methods might get modified by another developer afterwards(or by your self)

Still the point is (small operation * number of times) = might become heavy

This might is not acceptable when it is purely avoidable using other methods such as **pure pipes** or **manual calculations to variables**

He even has nice [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxmb6q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) setup for compare